# how to select files in bash, given the start filename

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a bash script and following are the env vars.

```
realToday=20140804

RlPrDay1=20140803
RlPrDay2=20140802
RlPrDay3=20140801
RlPrDay4=20140731
RlPrDay5=20140730
RlPrDay6=20140729 
RlPrDay7=20140728 
RlPrDay8=20140727 

RlNxDay1=20140805
RlNxDay2=20140806
RlNxDay3=20140807
RlNxDay4=20140808
 
today=20140729
time=115
```

and the lines are following:

```
    yst1="/3.0ftp/3h/${RlPrDay6}/${RlPrDay8}_yk-YYKK-${RlPrDay6}.gz"
    tod0="/3.0ftp/3h/${RlPrDay6}/${RlPrDay7}_yk-YYKK-${RlPrDay6}.gz"
    tom1="/2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay6}/${RlPrDay6}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay6}.gz"
    tom2="/2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay5}/${RlPrDay5}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay5}.gz"
    tom3="/2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay4}/${RlPrDay4}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay4}.gz"
    tom4="/2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay3}/${RlPrDay3}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay3}.gz"
    tom5="/2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay2}/${RlPrDay2}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay2}.gz"
    tom6="/2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay1}/${RlPrDay1}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay1}.gz"
    tom7="/7.0fcs/5h/${RlPrDay1}/${realToday}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay1}.gz"
    tom8="/7.0fcs/5h/${RlPrDay1}/${RlNxDay1}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay1}.gz"
    tom9="/7.0fcs/5h/${RlPrDay1}/${RlNxDay2}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay1}.gz"
    tom10="/7.0fcs/5h/${RlPrDay1}/${RlNxDay3}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay1}.gz"
    tom11="/7.0fcs/5h/${RlPrDay1}/${RlNxDay4}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay1}.gz"
```

Now I want to select and copy the files from

```
 /2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay6}/${RlPrDay6}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay6}.gz
```

to

```
/2.0mmt/1h/${RlPrDay2}/${RlPrDay2}_ky-KKYY-${RlPrDay2}.gz
```

only.

In short, I want to locate the file which name starts as `$today`.

Something like:

```
 if [[ ${time} -le 120 && ${time} -ge 97 && ${today} -lt ${realToday} ]]; then
      cp ${tom1} $dest/
      cp ${tom2} $dest/
      cp ${tom3} $dest/
      cp ${tom4} $dest/
      cp ${tom5} $dest/
    fi
```

Is there any way to select and copy the files providing the args `time`, `today` in bash script?

Comment: Use arrays. `tom=( first second third )`, not `tom1=first; tom2=second; tom3=third`, unless you **really** need to pass them through the environment. (In that latter case, there are still indirection tricks available -- iterating over prefixed variable names, for instance).

Comment: ...beyond that, though, yes -- `today_files=( "$today"* )` will put all files starting with the contents of `$today` into your array.